# JPedal flag org.jpedal.avoidCleanupRaster =?

Tags: java, jvm, tomcat7, out-of-memory, jpedal

I am using JPedal tool to convert PDF to images.
I can see following flag which tells JPedal to avoid reducing some large images as this can crash Java (information from link https://www.idrsolutions.com/jpedal/support/jvm-flags/):

```
-Dorg.jpedal.avoidCleanupRaster="true"
```

In general pdf to image conversion is working, however once in a while during converting large PDF to images it causes tomcat to stop without any information or logs.It seems it's simply an OutOfMemoryError that is not being printed.
Can anyone please tell me if I select flag value as false then is that a valid solution.

```
-Dorg.jpedal.avoidCleanupRaster="true"
```

Comment: What version of jpedal are you using?

Comment: version 1.5 : 49.0, super bit

Comment: That seems to me the java version - I meant the jpedal version like 4.93b (e.g. https://www.idrsolutions.com/jpedal/2013-release-notes)